# How to refresh Oracle APEX-5.1.2 reports region with data only when the corresponding backend database table datas changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Are there any mechanism **to invoke or trigger the event from back-end to page region report in Oracle APEX 5.1.2** only when the back-end database specific tables data changes. 

Set interval to time in page region  does unnecessary refresh even no data are changes or inserted.

Please gives the step by step procedure as i am newbie in apex as well as JavaScript, if solution available.

Comment: Your APEX version must be wrong as 5.2 isn't out yet.  Maybe 5.1.2?

Comment: sorry for mistakes

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the actual problem.  I can see from the tags that you already know it will involve technology like node.js to push notifications to the client, so you know as much as I do on this topic!